# Filtering data with AngularJS Filter. How to iterate over objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is my Filter:

```
app.filter('ticketsFilter', function (){
return function (input){
    var data = input;
    console.log("Filtered object:")
    console.log(data);
        return input;
};
});
```

This is my Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | ticketsFilter">
  <p> {{ticket.createdByName}} </p>
  <p> {{ticket.title}} </p>
  <p> {{ticket.toDpt}} </p>
</tr>
```

The tickets Object is a Object of Objects. On my DB, there are 4 instances of tickets. And, when my ticket hits the filter, the Filtered Object is displayed as:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I could not figure out how to acess these objects. I've tried to use $index, received a dependency injection. Tried to use a (for x in input) loop, but the console.log will only display the last object properties. I've tried for(i, i

I can properly acess my objects properties using this:

```
console.log(data[0].attribute);
```

But I dont know how to iterate and acess data[i] instead of data[0]. Well, any tips on how to acess my Object Objects index? I can give more code if needed.

Thanks for any advice.

**@EDIT**

This is how my console.log($scope.tickets) looks like:

```
fromDpt: Array[4]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
```

Every Object looks like this:

```
0: Object
__v: 0
_id: "55ddb1e6ca11301020ef9b77"
createdAt: "1440592358061"
createdById: "55d758ee3a7ff720141a18f8"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: Where are trying to access the individual elements?  why can't you just reference the `ticket` in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Have you / How have you defined $scope.tickets in your controller? Besides, your filter is just returning the same data and thus isn't filtering anything. I think you can just define $scope.tickets as the result of your DB call and then iterate over it with ng-repeat.

Comment: can you show an example of what you mean by "an object of objects"?  I *suspect* that you mean that it's something like `{tickets: { ticket:{}, ticket:{}, }}`...

Comment: @ryanyuyu, because I have { tickets : {ticket:{}, ticket{} }. This also answers your question.

Comment: @Claies, above answers is to you too. :)
Added more code.

Comment: @ABr, Yes, I have. I'm not filtering anything because I want to iterate over my objects first, I cant filter before reach my object. :P

Comment: you have to use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in tickets"` to iterate over the object.  That being said, filters will probably not work the way you expect when using this syntax, and ordering is not controllable.  You are better to convert this to an array first.  also, you will get the `fromDpt` array in this iterator, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @Claies, added more code about the Markup. :)

Comment: that isn't going to work with the data you have structured this way at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of you gave me great insight about this problem. I thank you every and each of you. Since none had a full answer, I'm going to summarize all the tips and create a full answer to this problem:

First of all. When I'm trying to iterate over

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | ticketsFilter">
```

the ticketsFilter will receive a instance of ticketS. TicketS is an Object containing multiple ticket Objects, and each ticket having some properties. So:

```
$scope.tickets = {
  ticket: { name: 'Philip', status: 'good' },
  ticket: { name: 'R2B21', status: 'sad' },
  ticket: { name: '42', status: 'good' },
  ticket: { name: 'MVW', status: 'bad' }
};
```

Knowing that my filter will receive tickets as input, I could reach every ticket inside of it with a proper for loop. This way:

```
app.filter('ticketsFilter', function () { 
  return function(tickets){
    for (var i = 0; i < tickets.length; i ++) { ...
```

Inside of the for loop, I will reach each and every ticket contained in tickets. So, I just need to grab them and check if they have the propertie that I want. I this case, I want to return only tickets that have a status of 'good'. So:

```
var ticket = tickets[i]; //Grabing the ticket inside the for loop.
if (ticket.status == 'good') { //Checking if my ticket is good.
```

Now, I need two things. First, I need to return my data and I need to push every filtered 'good' ticket into my returned data. I need to remember, tought, that the returned object must not be 1 ticket, but ticketS. Because of that, I'm going to create a empty array called filtered before the for loop. And, to push use my if to insert ticket[i] that have a propertie of status=='good'.

So, the full code will be:

```
app.filter('ticketsFilter', function (){
return function (tickets){
    //creating the empty object that will return data
    var data = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < tickets.length; i ++) {
        var ticket = tickets[i];
        if (ticket.status == 'good'){
            //Inserting 'good' ticket inside of data
            data.push(ticket);
        };
    };
    //And, finally, returning the data
    return data;
};
});
```

After that, If I have the Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | ticketsFilter">
  <p><b> {{ticket.name}} </b></p>
</tr>
```

It would display:

**Philip**

**42**

And that is it, iterating over an array of objects and checking their properties. I want to thank, again, every one that tried to help and want to sorry about my bad explanation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The code below will apply the filter on all objects within tickets and returning the complete array of objects:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter:ticketsFilter">
```

If you want to use the filter to alter the output of a specific item, you can apply the filter one level below the ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
   {{ticket.name | filter:ticketsFilter}}
</tr>
```

But it depends on what you want your filter to do. I suggest you to also take look at some info how to apply filters:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

If this does not work for you I would suggest you to be a bit more specific on what you want your filter to do.

Comment: I'm trying to find if some propertie inside my ticket is true and return only the tickets that have this true propertie.

Comment: If that is what you want, then you should add the filter on the tr tag on which you are using ng-repeat. ( My first option ) Then rewrite your filter to return only the output you need. Remember that you don't need to go over your objects inside your for since Ng-repeat is doing that while adding the filter to every ticket.

Comment: Thank you, ABr, I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

using the Ng-model and pasing the model as a filter...
here an exaple: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/njm96Luv/2/

```
<div class="field" ng-app="App">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model">
    <table ng-controller="Controller">
        <tr ng-repeat="item in table | filter:model">
            <td ng-class="item.style"><i ng-class="item.badge"></i> {{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

js

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('Controller', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.table = [
        {name : 'Dan', 
         badge: 'fa fa-futbol-o'
        },
        {name : 'Orlando', 
         badge: 'fa fa-bicycle'},
        {name : 'Dany', 
         badge: 'fa fa-bolt'}
   ];

    $scope.delete = function(item, index){
        item.deleted = true;
        item.style = 'deleted';

        function destroy() {
        $scope.table.splice(index, 1)
        }

        $timeout(function(){destroy();}, 3000);
    }
})
```

exaple: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/njm96Luv/2/

Comment: Thank you, Leo for. I've added a full answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

## below div will display the ticket as per my textbox input

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="tickets.Id">
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter:tickets">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is nest the ng-repeats. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I'm right you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
<div ng-repeat="myOtherObject in   ticket.someProperty | filter:something">
</div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the sloppy code, on mobile, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Added a full answers, @Perry. Thank you.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza Glad you got it sorted out!